Creating transient services from other transient service
Hopefully, someone will point me to the right direction here. I need some help in getting DI working with my angular services. I have the following code where my angular services are currently singleton.
export interface IMyHandler {
  run(): void;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyHandler1 implements IMyHandler {    
  private somethingElse = inject(SomeOtherClass);

  constructor() {
  }

  public run(): void {      
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyHandler2 implements IMyHandler {    
  private somethingElse = inject(SomeOtherClass);

  constructor() {
  }

  public run(): void {      
  }
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LookupService {

  private customHandlersMap: Map<string, IMyHandler> = new Map<string, IMyHandler>();

  constructor() {
    this.customHandlersMap.set('M1', inject(MyHandler1));
    this.customHandlersMap.set('M2', inject(MyHandler2));
  }

  public getHandlerByName(key: string) : IMyHandler {
     return this.customerHandlersMap.get(key);
  }
}

@Component({
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {
 constructor(private lookupService: LookupService) {
 }
 
 public callHandler(key: string) {
   this.lookupService.getHandlerByName(key).run();
 }
}

The above creates service as singleton. What I need is when I call MyComponent.callHandler() method, it gets me new instance of the class from the lookupService and then simply calls run() method on it. I tried using providers:  in MyComponent declaration, but it didn't seem to work, and also I don't want to list all IMyHandler instances there.

I validated your code, and it's working correctly. Below is a working example, where if you click the "watch parent service", then it sets a service property test on the parent.
Then if you click the "watch child service"  property on the child, it is not present in the child element, so maybe you missed adding all the three services to the providers array. Compare your code with this working example to identify the problem.
import { Component, Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export interface IMyHandler {
  run(): void;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyHandler1 implements IMyHandler {
  // private somethingElse = inject(SomeOtherClass);

  constructor() {
    console.log('MyHandler1 constructor');
  }

  public run(): void {
    console.log('MyHandler1');
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyHandler2 implements IMyHandler {
  // private somethingElse = inject(SomeOtherClass);

  constructor() {
    console.log('MyHandler2 constructor');
  }

  public run(): void {
    console.log('MyHandler2');
  }
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LookupService {
  test: any = null;
  private customHandlersMap: Map<string, IMyHandler> = new Map<
    string,
    IMyHandler
  >();

  constructor() {
    this.customHandlersMap.set('M1', inject(MyHandler1));
    this.customHandlersMap.set('M2', inject(MyHandler2));
  }

  public getHandlerByName(key: string): IMyHandler {
    return this.customHandlersMap.get(key) as IMyHandler;
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [LookupService, MyHandler1, MyHandler2],
  template: `
    <button (click)="callHandler('M1')">M1</button>
    <button (click)="callHandler('M2')">M2</button>
    <button (click)="getService()">watch service</button>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  service = inject(LookupService);

  constructor(private lookupService: LookupService) {}

  public callHandler(key: string) {
    this.lookupService.getHandlerByName(key).run();
  }
  getService() {
    // this.service.test = 'parent';
    console.log(this.service);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
    <app-child/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <button (click)="getService()">watch parent service</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  service = inject(LookupService);

  getService() {
    this.service.test = 'parent';
    console.log(this.service);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for response. This isn't quite what I want though. I could have more than 20 implementations of IMyHandler and I don't want to list them all in providers of the component. Is there a way to do it without listing MyHandler1, MyHandler2, and etc...? Maybe some kind of factory method from LookupService?

Naren: a spelling reminder, the fix for which I keep having to make. The contraction of "it is" is it's, i.e. it takes an apostrophe. If you have trouble remembering, just use the expansion instead.
